# Truncating titles from reddit API using multi-clamp.js

Tags: javascript, document, truncate, selectors-api

I'm trying to use (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-clamp)[multi-clamp.js] to clamp/truncate my titles that are being returned from the reddit api.

However, it is only working on the 1st retuned title rather than all of the titles. How would I ensure that the function runs on all of the titles returned from the api and not just the 1st?

```
const reddit = "https://www.reddit.com/r/upliftingnews.json?raw_json=1&limit=10"

async function getData() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(reddit);
        let data = await response.json()
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

getData()
    .then(data => data.data.children)
    .then(data => data.map(post => ({
        source: post.data.domain,
        author: post.data.author,
        link: post.data.url,
        img: (typeof (post.data.preview) !== 'undefined') ? post.data.preview.images[0].source.url : null,
        title: post.data.title,
    })))
    .then(data => data.map(render))

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

const render = post => {
    //console.log(post.data);
    const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.classList.add('news-item', `news-item--${ post.class }`);
    node.innerHTML = `
    <a class="news-item-link" href="${post.link}">
        <div style="background-image: url('${post.img}')" class="news-item-bg"></div>
        <div class="news-item-content">
            <h3 class="news-item-source">${post.source}</h3>
            <h2 class="news-item-title mb-2">${post.title}</h2>
        </div>
    </a>`;
    app.appendChild(node);

    new MultiClamp(document.querySelector('.news-item-title'), {
        ellipsis: '...',
        clamp: 2
    });
}
```

`new MultiClamp..` is where the clamping runs on the title selector but it's only clamping the first returned title, rather than all of them.

How do I get it to run on all titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` returns only the first element that matches the selector. Since you are executing it on the whole `document`, it will always get the first title that you appended to the document, and create many `new MultiClamp`s on it.

Instead, you need to select the one new title element in your new node:

```
function render(post) {
    const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.classList.add('news-item', `news-item--${ post.class }`);
    node.innerHTML = `
    <a class="news-item-link" href="${post.link}">
        <div style="background-image: url('${post.img}')" class="news-item-bg"></div>
        <div class="news-item-content">
            <h3 class="news-item-source">${post.source}</h3>
            <h2 class="news-item-title mb-2">${post.title}</h2>
        </div>
    </a>`;
    app.appendChild(node);

    new MultiClamp(node.querySelector('.news-item-title'), {
//                 ^^^^
        ellipsis: '...',
        clamp: 2
    });
}
```

Btw, using `innerHTML` with unescaped interpolation values opens up your application for XSS attacks. Better build the entire node contents using the DOM API as well.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the heads up about XSS attacks. Is there a better way I should be rendering the data? I'm not sure what you mean by "build the entire node contents using the DOM API as well"

Comment: I mean not using `innerHTML`, but only `document.createElement` and `appendChild`. For the text content, use `document.createTextNode` that you append or `node.textContent`.

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate the help. That pointed me to `createDocumentFragment` which I've now refactored it with.